# Electron packager: Need to read the installer name

Tags: electron, electron-packager

I am packaging my electron application using electron-packager and creating installer using electron-winstaller. Exe can be downloaded from different channels. reference of channel or site will be appended in exe file itself.

Once user starts the installation i need to get that reference from exe. and store it in my application or any file.
It will look like: MyApp_REF12345.exe

Any clue how i can achieve this?

Comment: kindly elaborate your question

Comment: Any workaround would be helpful.